# How to insert letters in between the textfield's text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

How do I insert letters in between a `TextField`'s text in flutter?

###### Example

Text in the text field: `I run faster than him.`

###### Expected Result

I want to move the curser before the `run` and type `can` .

```dart
TextField(
    controller: _controller,
    onChanged: (value) {
        // Do something when the text changes
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Enter your text',
    ),
),
```

Comment: can you make your question more clear? I can't understand it. but I think you should use formatters to do what you want. If you make it more clear, I'll create a formatted in an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is my example code, might be helpful

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _focus = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = "I run faster than him.";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              focusNode: _focus,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("change text field value"),
              onPressed: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focus);
                /// insert text
                _controller.text = "I can run faster than him.";
                /// change cursor position
                _controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: 5));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```